# Using a to-report procedure in Netlogo BehaviorSpace: "Measure runs using these reporters:"

Tags: netlogo

Is it possible to use a to-report function that reports multiple variables and updates with ticks in Netlogo behavior-space (measure runs using these reporters), so that as ticks update, the reported value is updated accordingly into spreadsheet?

```
    `to setup
      clear-all
      create-turtles 100 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
      reset-ticks
    end`

      to go
       move-turtles
       tick
        if ticks = 100 [
          stop
        ]
    end

    to move-turtles
      ask turtles [
        right random (90 + c)
        forward g + h
      ]
    end

    to-report pack
      ifelse (z? = true) [
        let a random-float 1.0
        let b random-float 2.0
        let c random-float 3.0
          if c > 1.5 [
           let g = a - b
           report g
          ]
           report a 
           report b
          ]
        [
        let d random-float 1.0
        let e random-float 2.0
        let f random-float 3.0
          if f > 1.5 [
           let h = d - e
           report h
           ]
           report d 
          report e
      ]
   ]
end
```

`z?` is a switch on the interface. When `z?` is switched on either g or a and b are reported, but when the switch is off, either h or d and e are reported (given the conditions that c and f are greater than 1.5 respectively).

If I call the report function `pack` in behavior space, within the `measure runs using these reporters`, field, the resulting spreadsheet does not show the tick-by-tick result updates for the values that are supposed to be reported (g or a and b, h or d and e, depending on whether the switch `z?` is on or off). The spreadsheet only contains the initializations associated with the setup procedure.

Also, I get a runtime error that says: `reached end of reporter procedure without report being called netlogo`

How can I get the `pack`reporter to output results of values as they update with ticks in the resulting spreadsheet from a batch simulation run in behaviorspace? (I want to it to act the the same way a `count turtles` entry into the `Measure runs using these reporters` field in behaviorspace would behave, except instead of turtle counts, it should show g or a and b at each tick, otherwise h, d and e at each tick in the spreadsheet ).

Comment: Does your `to-report` as you have written it above work for you if you just call it from the observer? Some issues: `let g = a - b` should be `set g a - b` assuming g is a global variable, and same for `let h = d - e`. `let e random-float 2.0` doesn't work for me, as `e` is reserved for e. Also, once `report` is called, the procedure ends and **only** that first item will be reported. So when you have `report a report b` in sequence, only `a` will be reported. I cut these errors and ran a BehaviorSpace experiment with `pack` reporting at each step correctly- try fixing those, it should work.

Comment: @LukeC Thanks for your comments. I fixed errors accordingly, and still couldn't get it to work. Could you paste your working code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up from comments:

I wasn't sure what you wanted to do with your double reports (`a` and `b` and `d` and `e`, so I used two different options. Since `c`, `g`, and `h` are referenced in several procedures, I assumed they are `globals`. The code I used:

```
globals [ c g h ]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 100 [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]
  reset-ticks
  set c 10
  set g 2
  set h 3
end


to go
  move-turtles
  tick
end


to move-turtles
  ask turtles [
    right random (90 + c)
    forward g + h
  ]
end


to-report pack
  ifelse (z? = true) [
    let a random-float 1.0
    let b random-float 2.0
    set c random-float 3.0
    if c > 1.5 [
      set g a - b
      report g
    ]
    report ( word a " " b )
  ]
  [
    let d random-float 1.0
    let ee random-float 2.0
    let f random-float 3.0
    if f > 1.5 [
      set h d - ee
      report h
    ]
    report d + ee    
  ]
end
```

Then, I set up the Behaviorspace experiment like this:
[image: Example Behaviorspace setup]

And I get Table output like this:

```
   run   z1. step                                   pack
1    2 FALSE    0                             0.18138234
2    2 FALSE    1                            1.676066247
3    2 FALSE    2                            0.403470969
4    1  TRUE    0                            -0.10139442
5    2 FALSE    3                            1.399234345
6    2 FALSE    4                           -0.887992861
7    1  TRUE    1  0.0671613060827172 1.5362438146989783
8    2 FALSE    5                           -0.864156125
9    2 FALSE    6                            1.626410602
10   1  TRUE    2  0.5789346091777932 1.1071709255628879
11   2 FALSE    7                            0.446313014
12   1  TRUE    3 0.7216825225835118 0.22072137498998523
```

**Edits:example 2**

Try this `pack-2` reporter:

```
to-report pack-2
  let x random 5
  let y random 7
  set g g + 1
  if z? [
    set c c * 1.2
  ]
  set h x + y
  report ( word x " " y )
end
```

Then, try setting up the BehaviorSpace experiment like this:

[image: Set up for the second experiment]

When I run that experiment I get updating values for `pack-2`, `c`, `g`, and `h` on a per-tick basis, which looks as below in Spreadsheet output:

```
   pack.2         c  g  h pack.2.1 c.1 g.1 h.1
1     0 0  12.00000  3  0      2 2  10   3   4
2     0 3  14.40000  4  3      2 1  10   4   3
3     3 5  17.28000  5  8      4 4  10   5   8
4     1 2  20.73600  6  3      4 0  10   6   4
5     4 6  24.88320  7 10      3 6  10   7   9
```

And like this in Table output (easier to process with R or whatever):

```
   X.run.number.    z. X.step. pack.2       c g h
1              1  true       0    3 0 12.0000 3 3
2              2 false       0    2 0 10.0000 3 2
3              1  true       1    4 4 14.4000 4 8
4              2 false       1    1 0 10.0000 4 1
5              1  true       2    4 1 17.2800 5 5
```

If I am still missing what you're trying to output, please let me know!

Comment: Awesome Luke, so just for clarification, besides the syntax errors, setting the parameters which were to be reported as global variables, thereby using 'set' instead of 'let' to assign the per-tick updating equations to them is what allowed them to behave as desired? Also, what was the purpose of 'report (word a " " b )' and is it reporting them as string characters?  Finally, what if I had five variables to update and report each tick, how would that be handled by the aforementioned statement or other means? Thanks a ton for enlightening me.

Comment: You can definitely get a reporter to work with `let`, but I added those `globals` so that I could use `go` with `c`, `g`, and `h`. I don't think that it was the global vs local variable that was causing the issue, but that the reporter was not functioning correctly- you can check if a reporter is working as desired by using a monitor on the interface, or just by calling it in the console. Next, `report (word ` " " b )` does indeed report them as strings- `report` can only return one value, and if you **need** both, that is one way to get them reported (as opposed to summing as with `d + ee`.

Comment: Of course, you would need to do more processing afterwards to pull out the numerical values from the string, but it is one way to "report" both in a single reporter, although it's a bit of a cheat and not convenient. As far as needing to have five variables tracked in your per-tick output, I would either include those variables directly in the  `Measure runs using these reporters:` text box, or make other separate reporters as you did for `pack`. It's simpler to just measure the reporters directly, but if you need to do some calculations beforehand, I think your approach does what you need.

Comment: Final question, can I use something like:  'report (word a " " b " " c " " d " " e) after assigning the variables with 'let', and have them print to spreadsheet file as opposed to table?

Comment: Yes, that definitely works in the code (other than the use of `e`), although I wouldn't personally recommend it, mainly because you end up having to do more data munging after the fact to pull out your values  and convert them to numeric data (and spreadsheet is wide format as opposed to long, but that's up to your preference).

Comment: The absolute last question ... I was wondering if I need to use `report` in a `to-report` function, could I use `type` or `print' instead?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147745/discussion-between-luke-c-and-nigus21).

Comment: Thanks, I tried that Luke, and it worked with one significant issue ... it is only reporting the first value of each of the variables and stopping. For some reason, I cannot get it to line by line updates of the parameters as ticks progress. Do you have any suggestions for tackling this issue. I figured you may have mentioned it in your comments and responses to my post but I was unable to locate the solution to this issue upon reading, any thoughts?

Comment: Please have a look at the second example I have edited into my answer above, maybe that will help.

Comment: Awesome, what if you write the set g and c and h as a procedures and call them in your report function, will it yield same result?

Comment: Awesome, what if you write the set g and c and h equations as separate procedures and call them in your report function, will it yield same result? E.g. "to set-g ..." that might be the mistake I am making? Mine only reports the results for the first step.

Comment: Also, must I initialize the globals in setup as you did or can i initialize them in the reporter?

Comment: Yes, I got the desired result even by calling a procedure within the `to-report` called `set-g-z` that updated the `g` and `z` values. No, you don't need to initialize the `globals` in setup, but if you don't they will start off with a value of 0 (as do all declared variables). Remember that as soon as `report` is called in the `to-report`, the procedure **stops** completely-
 any code after that `report` will not be run.
 See [report](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#report) and [to-report](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#to-report).

Comment: I left you about 4 chats  in our chat session you started up that sum up the last part of this question, I think once we get through those, the issue should be resolved ... Let me know your thoughts on them ...

Comment: posted a last ditch effort at solution to issue in chat, let me know what you think, thanks a million.